# How to filter record in REST API with value containing &

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to fetch record from list with RESP API.I want to filter record with 'eq'.

following is the rest endpoint which I am trying,

`_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Experts')/items?$select=Column1,Column2$filter=Column1 eq 'A&B'`

I am getting following error,

`The expression "Column1 eq 'A" is not valid.`

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to explain the Why with an answer,

The **&** character indicates a new Variable IN the URI string,

If you need it as a character, you have to escape it,
telling the Server **not** to threat it as a separator.

Multiple methods of escaping characters:

[Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)

Answer (score 2):

URL parameter values should be encoded while using them in REST.

```
var colVal = encodeURIComponent("A&B");
```

then use this variable in your query.

```
var endPointURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Experts')/items?$select=Column1,Column2$filter=(Column1 eq '" + colVal + "')"
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Executing our items via an ajax request 
    var colVal = encodeURIComponent("A&B");
    $.ajax({
        url: "siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq '"+colVal+"'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below URL.

```
http://siteURL/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Experts')/items?$select=Column1,Column2$filter=Column1 eq 'A\&B'
```